# Getting device location when the app is in foreground, background or terminated state in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, location

I am trying to get the device's location after a fixed interval, say 15mins, no matter if the application is in foreground, background or terminated state.
The application we are developing is the critical alert system for which we need to fetch user's location at a particular time interval even when the app is terminated. I have used BGProccessingTask for that purpose with earliestBeginDate = 3600. Even after specifying it for an hour, it begins the task anytime like 8-9 hours later or sometimes more.
Description says - 'Setting this property does not guarantee that the task will begin at the specified date'.

Would appreciate it if someone could help.
Also, is there any other solution for this?

Comment: You should search. This question has been asked numerous times. You cannot execute any code on iOS on a fixed time interval. You can use significant location monitoring to get notified (and even relaunched) when the user moves approximately 500m. Unfortunately what you "need" and what is possible on ios are different things

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to "Signing & Capabilities"
2. Under "Background Modes" add "Location Updates"
3. Make sure you add to the info.plist file all the relevant Usage-description keys (NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription, NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription)
4. Be ready that the next time you submit, you will be asked by the Apple Review team why is your app using this background mode

Comment: Thanks Arik. I have already done these things. Everything works just fine when the app is in foreground and background. But when the app is terminated/suspending, thats when I dont get regular updates.